# Nginx ingress server exposed as nodeport with external ip is reachable from within the cluster, but not from outside

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I am running a kubernetes cluster using kubeadm and virtualbox. To manage traffic with the outside world, I have an nginx service as a nodeport running with an external ip.

```
$kubectl get svc --all-namespaces

ingress-nginx   nginx-ingress          NodePort    10.97.117.136   192.168.290.89 80:31738/TCP,443:32320/TCP,22:31488/TCP   26m
```

When I

```
curl 10.97.117.136:80
```

from inside the cluster,

I get

```
default backend - 404.
```

However, when I

```
curl 192.168.290.89:31738
```

from outside the cluster,

I get

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.290.89 port 31738: Connection timed out
```

Does anyone understand this behavior and know how to remedy it?

Comment: One thing you might check is the routing table on the host you're curling to 192.168.x.x address. That's a local IP address, and if you're outside of that cluster, or if your routing table doesn't have the right entries, you might be trying to connect to a maching you can't access.

Comment: What I meant, in this case, by outside the cluster still refers to the same physical machine that the virtualbox is running on.

Comment: can you ping `192.168.290.89`? I would first check that the node is reachable, before investigating any kubernetes misconfiguration

Comment: Unfortunately, pinging does not work either.

Comment: Follow this instruction to setup correct networking between host and VM - https://serverfault.com/questions/225155/virtualbox-how-to-set-up-networking-so-both-host-and-guest-can-access-internet